# How to set autoCommit to false in Websphere 8.5.5 database connection

Tags: java, websphere, oracle12c

I have an application deployed on Websphere 8.5.5 using an Oracle 12c db connection and I am not able to login to the application. The error I get is:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Could not commit with auto-commit set on
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.commit(PhysicalConnection.java:4439)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.commit(PhysicalConnection.java:4486)
    at oracle.jdbc.OracleConnectionWrapper.commit(OracleConnectionWrapper.java:140)
    at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcConnection.commit(WSJdbcConnection.java:1144)
    at
```

Is there a way in Websphere to set this property to false? So far I have tried creating a custom property for the datasources autoCommit = false , type=boolean.

Any ideas? Cheers

Answer (score 1):

There is  IBM support page that describe your problem, I hope this help.

[IBM support page.](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21600078)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there is a problem with `Oracle 12c` drivers.

I was having the same problem here on Websphere Liberty Profile using `ojdbc7.jar` driver.  I've download 11.2.0.3's `ojdbc6.jar` driver from [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/jdbc-112010-090769.html), and suddenly, it started working.